# Prove that if $I$ is a right ideal of $R$ and $I$ is a direct summand of $R$ then $I=eR$ for some idempotent $e \in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that if $I$ is a right ideal of $R$ and $I$ is a direct summand of $R$ then $I=eR$ for some idempotent $e \in R$ Also, $R$ is a unital ring.

So $I$ is a direct summand, this means there is another ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $R = I \oplus J$ and $J+I = R$ and $J \cap I = \emptyset$... I'm a little bit lost here, would appreciate some help!

Comment: $J\cap I=\emptyset$ is wrong: two ideals will *have* to share $0$, so their intersection can never be smaller than $\{0\}$.  $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ are two totally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$1=e+(1-e)$$
where $e \in I$ and $1-e \in J$.

Note that
$$e(1-e)=(1-e)e= e-e^2$$
belongs to both $I$ and $J$, because they are right ideals. Thus,
$$e-e^2=0$$
which shows that $e$ is idempotent.

Now, clearly $eR \subseteq I$. To show the converse, for all $x \in I$
$$x-ex = (1-e)x \in I \cap J$$
Thus $x-ex=0$, i.e. $x=ex \in eR$.

Comment: Why is $1 - e \in J$?

Comment: Since $1 \in I+J$, you have $1=e+f$ with $e \in I$ and $f \in J$. But $1-e=f \in J$

Answer (score 1):

Let $1$ be the unit of $R$, and write $1=e+f$ for some $e\in I$, $f\in J$.  If $x\in I$, we have $$x=1x=ex+fx=ex,$$ so $I=eR$.  Furthermore, letting $x=e$ in the above calculation shows that $e$ is an idempotent.

Additionally, note that this is not true if we do not assume that $R$ is unital.  For then we can consider $R=C_0(\{0,1\}\times \mathbb R)$, $I=C_0(\{0\}\times\mathbb R)$ and $J=C_0(\{1\}\times\mathbb R)$.  Then we have $R=I\oplus J$, but there are no idempotents in $R$.

Comment: Why does $fx = 0$?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that $I$ was a *right* ideal.  I'll need to think about this.

Comment: I need to as well!

Comment: Well if $J$ is a right ideal, then $J\ni fx=x-ex\in I$, so $fx=0$.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume $J$ is a right ideal.